# css command that does the same effect as a.selected, but for a <p>

Tags: css, hover, href, selected

I want my `p` to change color as soon as I click on it, and come back to the original color as soon as I click on another `p`. 
Somehow like it is done for a list of `a href`, where you use the command `a.selected`.

Is this possible for `p`? and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Clicking on a link will not give it a selected class. That is done with either JavaScript or server side code. You would have to do something similar for the paragraph.

Comment: Do you mean `a:selected` instead of `a.selected`? The former uses a dynamic pseudo-class, the latter matches by class, not dynamically (unless you have JavaScript code that dynamically changes the class).

Comment: Oops, sorry, there is no `:selected` pseudo-class; I confused this with `:focus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a `p` element is not selectable, but on modern browsers, and by the HTML5 CR, you can make it selectable by assigning a positive [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) value to it. Then clicking on such an element will set focus on it, and it will match the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afocus) pseudo-class. Example:

```
<style>
p:focus { color: red; outline: none }
</style>
<p tabindex=10>Hello world!
<p tabindex=20>Hi again.
<p tabindex=30>The end.
```

The `outline: none` declaration is included, because without it, browsers will draw some kind of focus rectangle around the element. Of course if you want that rectangle (which is different in different browsers), omit this declaration or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just give your `<p>` a class and use `:hover` to change it's colour?

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m7cY7/)

Comment: hover is not enough, I want it to stay green (in your case) when I click and move my mouse away..